# Is it possible to bind multiple controls to filter one NSArrayController?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have one table view that should be filtered by values of search field and by element of dropdown list simultaneously.
Currently I've binded search field to array controller and it works as it should. But I have no idea how to add constrains from another control - drop down list so it wouldn't reset array filtered by search but filter its current results.

Comment: How is the filtering triggered now?  Is it triggered when you add text into your search field through bindings, or does the search field have an action method defined for it?

Comment: Also, will the user be able to more than one round of search field then drop down.  If so, do you want to start from the unfiltered list if the user either does another search or chooses another constraint?

Comment: Now it is done through bindings. Search and drop down constrains are applied to unfiltered list so I want to get intersection of sets chosen from the whole array.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this with bindings alone. One way I can think of is to have the search field set a predicate (but not filter) for its action method, and then do the filtering using that predicate and one generated from the drop down list after the choice is made there.  But, a lot depends on how you want the work flow to go -- if you could provide more info on that, it would be helpful.

Comment: It seems like bindings are not very useful there. I'll try to make it with predicate property which takes values from controls and bind it to my array controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still do not know if it is possible.

So i've chose another way to solve my problem.

1. Create an outlet to NSArrayController
2. Subscribe to notifications from controls. (NSControlTextDidChangeNotification and NSComboBoxSelectionDidChangeNotification)
3. Use setFilterPredicate to set new programmatically created predicate for my NSArraycontroller.

Works as expected and almost no bindings used.